# Terraform inside of container deletes files

Tags: docker, terraform, ubuntu-18.04

I am finding that docker on my Ubuntu 18.04 host is not retaining files mounted into the container on the host.

Image: `hashicorp/terraform`

I'm using `--mount` to bind a directory into the container, the directory is where the terraform config files are stored. I then execute the container which executes terraform which then writes its state files and all the other things.
In 70% of all cases those files don't survive the container. I can see them being created on the host while the container is running, but when the container is done doing its thing the files disappear.
Is that a docker or a terraform issue?

Adding more info:

`docker run --mount type=bind,source='/home/david/demo',target=/demo -w /demo -it hashicorp/terraform plan -out tfstate`

```
terraform version 
0.11.13
```

```
docker version
Client:
 Version:           18.09.5
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.8
 Git commit:        e8ff056
 Built:             Thu Apr 11 04:43:57 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.5
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.8
  Git commit:       e8ff056
  Built:            Thu Apr 11 04:10:53 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

Comment: Hmm... sounds like a Docker issue, Terraform shouldn't be deleting state files (I'm assuming you're storing your state locally, not using remote state?). Are other files (new, modified, etc.) surviving the container's lifetime, or is this unique to Terraform state files? And - 70% of the time, that sounds strange. Is there anything else changing in the environment that might be affecting this?

Comment: Yes, state is all stored locally inside the `mount` directory and I can see them pop up on the host and once the container is done, in most cases those files get deleted. Nothing happening on the host which would delete these files.

Comment: You can check if there is enough space of the volume to store the files.

Comment: @CharlesXu there is. On the host I can easily create GBs of data in that directory. The files get created, just deleted after the container ran.

Comment: Can you add information regarding the command that you use to launch your docker?, maybe your docker file too? and finally, can you provide versions for docker and terraform?

Comment: @Ikaro0 done. I'm using the image straight from docker hub as mentioned

Comment: @DavidO'Brien - I see this is happening with the `terraform plan` but is it also happening with `terraform apply` not updating the `.tfstate`? `plan` does not store any persistent files on its own unless you specifiy the `-out=path` parameter

Comment: @Ewan my bad, I forgot that I AM adding the `-out` parameter. Like I said, I can see that the files are being created, but then they disappear even with the `-out` specified.

Answer (score 0):

After reading all comments on your question I'm going to sum up how I've test your scenario and my outcome

My docker version:

```
Docker version 18.09.1, build 4c52b90
```

Terraform:

```
Terraform v0.11.13
+ provider.azurerm v1.24.0
```

I've created a folder which contains my main.tf file with the following configuration:

```
provider "azurerm" {
    version = "=1.24.0"
    subscription_id = "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
    client_id = "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
    client_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX="
    tenant_id = "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
    name = "testResourceGroup"
    location = "westus"
}
```

I'm behind a proxy so I've executed this the fist time and because I'm connecting to azure I've used init to be able to download the plugin:

```
docker run --env HTTPS_PROXY="http://myproxyfqdn:port" --rm --mount type=bind,source='/Docker/NFS/terraform',target='/terraform' -w /terraform -it hashicorp/terraform:full init
```

After this execution the folder on my host refreshed creating .terraform folder with the plugin:

```
# ls -ltra
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  759 Apr 23 09:00 main.tf
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Apr 23 09:09 .terraform
```

then I executed the plan with -out parameter that created my plan file for later use:

```
# docker run --env HTTPS_PROXY="http://myproxyfqdn:port" --rm --mount type=bind,source='/Docker/NFS/terraform',target='/terraform' -w /terraform -it hashicorp/terraform:full plan -out testplan
Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...
The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be
persisted to local or remote state storage.


------------------------------------------------------------------------

An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  + azurerm_resource_group.rg
      id:               <computed>
      location:         "westus"
      name:             "testResourceGroup"
      tags.%:           <computed>

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

That created the plan file on my folder:

```
# ls -ltra
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  759 Apr 23 09:00 main.tf
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Apr 23 09:09 .terraform
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5291 Apr 23 09:11 testplan
```

And then applying the plan created terraform.tfstate:

```
# docker run --env HTTPS_PROXY="http://myproxyfqdn:port" --rm --mount type=bind,source='/Docker/NFS/terraform',target='/terraform' -w /terraform -it hashicorp/terraform:full apply testplan
azurerm_resource_group.rg: Creating...
  location: "" => "westus"
  name:     "" => "testResourceGroup"
  tags.%:   "" => "<computed>"
azurerm_resource_group.rg: Creation complete after 2s (ID: /subscriptions/8d43a801-58b6-4dde-84cc-...c60e6/resourceGroups/testResourceGroup)

Apply complete! Resources: 1 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

Updates on host folder:

```
# ls -ltra
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  759 Apr 23 09:00 main.tf
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Apr 23 09:09 .terraform
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5291 Apr 23 09:11 testplan
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3748 Apr 23 09:11 terraform.tfstate
```

I did not had problems and every execution did update data on the host folder.

Comment: I'm wondering if it's something docker on Ubuntu related.
I restarted the OS, launch two ZSH terminals, one to check the directory's contents, the other one to run the docker container.
Sometimes the plan file survives the container, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Might be a race condition between docker and terraform...
Executing terraform inside the container from a script like this seems to "fix" it:

`cd ../demo; terraform plan -out tfstate; terraform apply tfstate; sleep 1`

Comment: Did any answer in this post solve in anyway your problem?, did you find the root cause of it?